# C# XML Serialization/DeSerialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm having a look at XML Serialization and have serialized as such:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T data)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    //Overridden to use UTF8 for compatability with Perl XML::DOM
    StringWriterUTF8 sw = new StringWriterUTF8();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, data);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

I use it as such:

```
string serializedData = Serializer.Serialize<List<InputData>>(rawDataCollection);
```

Which produces:

```
<ArrayOfInputData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-                instance"                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <InputData>
        <dose>100mg/kg</dose> 
        <compound>AZ13279746-001</compound> 
    </InputData>
</ArrayOfInputData>
```

For some reason, I can't include the header which was xml version 1.0 encoding UTF8.

Now, when I try to deserialize with

```
public static object DeSerialize<T>(string data)
{
    StringReader rdr = new StringReader(data);
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T i;
    i = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(rdr);

    return i;
}
```

I get an error saying invalid xml at 2,2.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think the mg/kg is failing..  I just lack the knowlage to explain properly. But I think the / is being seens as a "escape"-somethingwhateveritiscalled...  ggah I should have just shut up and stop making a fool out of myself :P

Comment: @Levisaxos - Ha.....I don't think it is that as it says invalid at 2,2 which would be the A in <ArrayOfInputData>, if you also include the header line. I think it's because it's expecting maybe <InputData> to be there?  I'm not sure either, hence why i've thrown it over to the wonderful people at SO  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's a typo, or a genuine mistake in the output, but you have an erroneous space in your XML.

```
< /ArrayOfInputData>
```

Comment: as no further answers shall be forthcoming on this( see my answer), then I have accepted yours. Spend wisely  :)

Comment: @Darren: Thanks, that's very generous.

Answer (score 3):

Have now fixed it:

```
public static object DeSerialize<T>(string data)
    {

       StringReader rdr = new StringReader(data);

       XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));


       var result = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(rdr);


       return result; 



    }

var fl = (List<InputData>)Serializer.DeSerialize<List<InputData>>(serializedData);
```

Comment: You can return T, rather than object - would save you some casting in the future.