# Storing and retrieving data from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I storage a set of user provided data in a file. When I took over the project, everything was saved to a plain text file. I redesigned it and now, the storage is an XML file. When the process starts, I read the XML file using *XDocument* and *XElement* classes. When I've obtained the values I put them in a constructor of my executing object.

I wonder if there's a way to automagically read in the XML data so that it, sort of, transforms (or is converted to) an instance of my object.

So, instead of:

```
XElement fromFile = XElement.Load(pathName);
XElement newStuff =
  new XElement("MainNode",
    new XElement("SubNode1", myObject.valueOfSubNode1),
    new XElement("SubNode2", myObject.valueOfSubNode2));
fromFile.ReplaceAll(newStuff);

XmlTextWriter writer = ...;
fromFile.Save(writer);
```

I'd like to "store" the instance of *myObject* itself. I'm assuming that's possible. I have no idea how or even where to start.

Comment: Keyword is *serialization* . Google for *XmlSerializer*...

Comment: Xml Serialization and Deserialization may be of assistance here

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. Sorry. I'd like to skip the XML format. I'd like to storage the instance of my object in a file and then restore that information to a (new) instance of that class. Is that what's called serialization? I'm uncertain because you mentioned *Xml* in *XmlSerializer*.

Comment: OK, then try binary serialization, ref http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

Comment: `I'd like to storage the instance of my object in a file and then restore that information to a (new) instance of that class`. Yes it is called serialization. And you have many alternatives for that. XmlSerializer, BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter, JavaScriptSerializer, DataContractSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer etc.

Comment: Cool. I'll google that right away. Should I aim for binary serialization or is xml-ish serialization just as good?

Comment: Pros and cons for both. Binary is more efficient and will be faster, and if it is only your program that is serializing and desrializing then should be fine. Xml of course is an open standard, and could be transportable, and potentially user editable (if you want that sort of thing, although this could be very dangerous as well). Depends on the scenario

Answer (score 1):

to serialize a type to XML:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T data)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, data);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

to deserialize from XML back into your object:

```
public static object DeSerialize<T>(string data)
{
  StringReader rdr = new StringReader(data);

  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

  var result = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(rdr);

  return result;
}
```

also have a look here: [C# XML Serialization/DeSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661227/c-sharp-xml-serialization-deserialization)

Comment: OK, so I'm getting the impression that my switch to XML format was right spot on. I just need to improve the actual data transporting. Just a quick question before I start to google the serialization methods. How does the original class defining my object to be serialized tell the serializing class how to do it?

Comment: there are standard methods of you can use attributes like XMLIgnore or XMLAttribute, XmlArray etc in defining your class, check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AndreasJohansson Google a bit more. In a decent example you'll see the properties of the class marked with attributes, such a XmlList, XmlElement etc. A tip though, the more complex the object, the more times you'll be found banging your head on the desk and longing for a nice simlple text file.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Oh, so that's what it was... This scary brackety thingies above each property and class... Now I get it. As for the banging, it might be so. But at least I learned something new. Plus, I feel that it's the right direction to go in as I want to become a skilled C# developer.

Comment: -1 for not placing the `StringReader` and `StringWriter` in `using` blocks. Yes, I _know_ that those particular classes don't use unmanaged resources today, but what about tomorrow, and what about establishing good habits in the readers