# Where to put functionality of serializing a custom class?

Tags: c#

I'm starting to work with the serialization now and I think I got my class serializable after asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488330/storing-and-retrieving-data-from-an-xml-file).

Now I wonder if it's regarded a good, bad, depending or indifferent design to place the serialization methods **inside** the said class.

Suppose I have my class like this.

```
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class SerializableClass
{
  public SerializableClass() { }

  [XmlElement("PropertyOne")]
  public String PropertyString { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("PropertyTwo")]
  public int PropertyInt { get; set; }

  public Object PropertyObject { get; set; }
}
```

Would it make sense to add methods like these, to let the object (de)serialize itself?

```
public String SerializeMe()
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass));
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
  return writer.ToString();
}

public static SerializableClass DeSerialize(String input)
{
  StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(SerializableClass);
  return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as SerializableClass;
}
```

I would, of course, implement these with *try-catch*, *using* and some kind of file reader and only specify the path. Is it doable? Recommended? Common? (I've never used serialization implemented by me, so please bear with me if the question seems strange.)

Answer (score 2):

Because the `XmlSerializer` will recognise the serialization attributes, why not use generic implementations to prevent code duplication?

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(object item)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public static T DeSerialize<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as T;
    }
```

Comment: Because this particular example is just for learning how to do that and I can be sure that this is the only serialization my small example will need. In the future, though, sure, generic is mostly better. However, my question was if it's wise to package in the functionality to self (de)serialization. Am I to understand that you think *nope*?

Comment: I would say no for the actual process of *serialization*.  If you needed to perform some kind of object transformation that was specific to that type, then it would make sense to include that transformation function within the type itself.  The serialization step will always remain the same, you just change what you feed into the serializer.

Comment: Ah, just as I though, then. Thanks! I'll be doing something **very** class specific during the operation. So, I'm guessing it's a yes, provided the special circumstances. Cool! +1 for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both implementations, and I can only say that it depends on the situation.

It is great to do this in some cases -

```
var object = new SerializableClass {PropertyString = "foo", PropertyInt = 22};
var xml = object.Serialize();
```

However, in a lot of other cases, Serialization/Deserialiazation happens while transferring it over a channel like http. In which case, the objects to be serialized are mostly DTO. This is where @Oliver's generic implementation comes in handy, and this is one case where I would like to keep the serialization logic out of DTO, to make it generic.

EDIT 1 - Adding the code that has Serialization/Deserialization working -

I tried using your snippets, and was able to serialize/deserialize. Some minor changes though -

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Serialization
{
    [XmlRoot("Settings")]
    public class SerializableClass
    {
        public SerializableClass() { }

        [XmlElement("PropertyOne")]
        public String PropertyString { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("PropertyTwo")]
        public int PropertyInt { get; set; }

        public Object PropertyObject { get; set; }

        public String SerializeMe()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass));
            var writer = new StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            return writer.ToString();
        }

        public static SerializableClass DeSerialize(String input)
        {
            var reader = new StringReader(input);
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableClass));
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SerializableClass;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class SerializerTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void SerializationTest()
        {
            var serializableClass = new SerializableClass { PropertyInt = 23, PropertyString = "foo", PropertyObject = "bar"};
            Console.WriteLine(serializableClass.SerializeMe());
        }

        [Test]
        public void DeserializationTest()
        {
            var deserializedXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16:""?>" +
                                    @"<Settings xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">" +
                                    @"<PropertyOne>foo</PropertyOne><PropertyTwo>23</PropertyTwo><PropertyObject xsi:type=""xsd:string"">bar</PropertyObject></Settings>";
            var serializableClass = SerializableClass.DeSerialize(deserializedXML);
            Console.WriteLine(serializableClass.PropertyInt);
            Console.WriteLine(serializableClass.PropertyString);
            Console.WriteLine(serializableClass.PropertyObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my code fault in itself? I'm getting an error. *There was an error reflecting type 'MyNamespace.MyClass'.* It gets right when I try to read the `typeof(MyClass)`. No idea what to do... :(

Comment: @AndreasJohansson - can you try calling `GetType()` instead? Since you want the type of the class in the member of the same class?

Comment: Sorry, the same problem. Could it have to do with the fact that one of my fields that I try to serialize it *Uri*? And the other is a custom class *MyCustomSubClass*? Do I have to stringify the properties somehow or can I only XML-ize Strings?

Comment: Is there a way I can see the code? You can edit the question, if you are ok with sharing the code.

Comment: It's just like I just edited. The only difference is that *String* is really typed *Uri* and *int* is really typed *MyClass* (literally). I also tried to remove the brackets from all properties and only put them on *String* but it was the same result. I don't understand the error message. It's too general.

Comment: Wait! I think I might have found something. Some nice #¤%& has edited the file while I was gone from the computer. There's actually an inner, sealed class inside and it has the attribute of *XmlRoot*. How can I circumvent the issue without having to break out the inner class?!

Comment: Nope. False alarm. It doesn't make any sense to me. I'm creating a new class and now I'm getting it to run through but the returned string is just the default info. No internal tags with the actual data... Maybe it's time to realize that I'm to stupid. Sight.  :(

Comment: @AndreasJohansson - I've updated my answer with what works for me (used nunit). Am able to see the output in console.